# Rosserial with ChipKit Max 32

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to setup rosserial communication together with my ChipKit Max32 microcontroller.

When I try to compile I get this error:

> Sketch_nov11a.cpp:7:17: fatal error: ros.h: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.

I've tried to use the same code for my Arduino Mega 1280 board and it works fine. I have looked at the tutorial for rossial_client but wasn't able to make a code for the ChipKit board.

I am a new programmer but I think the problem is that the ChipKit board have PIC32 architecture instead of the traditional avr.

My system details :

- Ubuntu 10.04
- As MPIDE: Arduino 022-chipkit-linux32-20110619

  - Downloaded from https://github.com/chipKIT32/chipKIT32-MAX/downloads

So, my question is how to setup the rosserial_package for my ChipKit Max 32 board?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11896/rosserial-with-chipkit-max-32/) by [Rathesan Ravendran](https://answers.ros.org/users/1358/rathesan-ravendran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the [tutorial on adding new platforms](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Adding%20Support%20for%20New%20Hardware). You have to create a hardware definition and then create ros.h as described so that you can use your hardware definition.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0